# Webhook response not working api.ai:Failed to parse SDKResponse from http_response Actions On Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using api.ai webhook for Action on Google implementation. I am following request and response format documented here

Response which I am sending back from webhook is

```
{
    "speech": "Ok I am doing the stuff",
    "displayText": "Ok I am doing the stuff",
    "data": {
        "google": {
            "expect_user_response": false,
            "is_ssml": false,
            "permissions_request": {
                "opt_context": "",
                "permissions": []
            }
        }
    },
    "contextOut": []
}
```

When I am testing this on Web Simulator for Google home, it is saying "Your Agent is not responding right now. Try again soon" with following response JSON

```
{
    "response": "Car Bot isn’t responding right now. Try again soon.\n",
    "audioResponse": "//NExAASW..."content_copy,
    "debugInfo": {
        "sharedDebugInfo": [
            {
                "name": "ExecutionResponse",
                "debugInfo": "Failed to..."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The debug info in the response is

> "Failed to parse SDKResponse from http_response: 'HTTP/1.1 200
>   OK\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Length:
>   218\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nDate: Sun, 08 Jan 2017 21:47:00
>   GMT\r\nServer: nginx/1.11.2\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials:
>   true\r\nAssistant-Interaction-Error-Code:
>   1\r\nAssistant-Interaction-Error-Message: Empty speech
>   response\r\nCache-control: no-cache=\"set-cookie\"\r\nSet-Cookie:
>   AWSELB=9D5B4D210CCFFAF1BE1E0CD7C7E6FCBD7B46140CAA45DBF2953C1CA6A2C5B5AD15740DAC3D9FC21AE7E6356E101785BA33F8274D819A39085F4BDBBE52D3F44CD1BB461230;PATH=/\r\nX-Cache:
>   Miss from cloudfront\r\nVia: 1.1
>   51c76241371dfc20d25094a51b4759eb.cloudfront.net
>   (CloudFront)\r\nX-Amz-Cf-Id:
>   bP2EaYL-00IkMABSCWhwbaDr5GU7sIgC02OB-31LGojecexWQayetQ==\r\n\r\n{\"message\":\"Empty
>   speech
>   response\",\"apiResponse\":{\"id\":\"ac3551e9-1f71-4f38-8ef7-efa8acff78aa\",\"timestamp\":\"2017-01-08T21:47:00.191Z\",\"result\":{},\"status\":{\"code\":200,\"errorType\":\"success\"},\"sessionId\":\"1483912013331\"}}'"

I am not getting what is wrong here.

**UPDATE:**

I have converted my message in speech to ASCII Characters but now Home is responding with the following message.

```
I'll just need to get your from Google. Is that ok?
```

Instead of what I am sending in the response attached to the speech label. Also JSON shown in simulator is not what I am returning from webhook.

Comment: You write that you are testing it with 'Web Simulator for Google home'.  I assume you got to that via the API.AI integrations page - cause if you went straight to the web simulator it would not work with an API.AI implementation.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I went it through API.AI clicking the preview button. Also, the welcome message after I say "Talk to my Agent" making me clear that I am at right spot.

Comment: @Tom Updated the question actually I need to send speech in ASCII format but now new issues arised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you figured out, your first problem was likely because you had non-ASCII characters in your text.

With the update, the problem is likely because you are specifying the `permissions_request` but not asking for any permissions. If you omit this part completely, the normal dialog flow should continue as you expect.